# Consisting Error (Error: cannot find 'ld') in codeblocks after deleting my project and try running the "Hello World" programm in c++

Tags: c++, error-handling, linker, codeblocks, gdprconsentform

I just startet coding and follow a book to get into coding. Now, I have this error but cannot figure out what causes the error. Any Ideas?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjeir.png)

I checked my compiler and the compiler should be fine. I think the problems either is the debugger or a file missing somewhere. I actually dont know what this error means and couldnt figure it out googling. Thanks for your help!

Comment: the linker is missing, either you haven't installed one or its not on your path

Comment: [ld is the linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work). After the compiler has finished translating your source code into executable objects, the linker assembles the objects, resolves any outstanding connections between the objects, and produces a program you can run.

Comment: Usually the linker is bundled with the compiler as part of what's called a toolchain. If you have a compiler and didn't do anything particularly strange installing the compiler, you should have a linker. To determine why it cannot be found we most likely need to inspect your IDE's configuration. That's really hard to do over the Internet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After trying to find a solution without success i decided to uninstall everything, start from scratch and re-downloaded everything. At least it works now. @user4581301

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help, but good that you have the tools sorted out.